# "Loading Checklog" error while loading quartz composition using Quartz Composer Patch Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, quartz-graphics, cocoa-bindings

I've created a composition in Quartz Composer, and am following the examples on "[Quartz Composer Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzComposer/qc_play_ib_input/qc_play_ib_input.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001357-CH208-TPXREF101#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001357-CH208-CJBFDCJC)" on Apple's website for connecting it to a XIB.

My goal is to be able to bind inputs in my Quartz Composition with UI controls (sliders, keyboard input, etc.) within my Cocoa application.  It seems that this tutorial is sufficient for what I want to do.

However, I can't get the Quartz Composer Patch Controller to load my composition.  I add the Patch Controller to my XIB document window, then I go to "Load Composition".

[image]

Every time I click "Load Composition", I choose my file and it gives me an error message box that says "Loading Failed: Loading CheckLog".

Here's what may be interesting: **I can view my composition if I load it with a QCView object, but can't load it in the Patch Controller.**

[image]

I've tried loading other compositions, I get the same error.  I tried in a different computer, on a new project, same XCode version (4.0.1), and I still get the error.

I've only done the steps outlined in the tutorial, and I am referencing the Quartz framework in my project.  My first thought is that there might be some procedures that are not outlined in the programming guide that I may be skipping.

So how do I resolve this error? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the “CheckLog” bit means that there’s something in the system log (open /Applications/Utilities/Console.app and look under Console Log). There might also be something in ~/Library/Logs/. (Shamefully bad UI in any case, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem - solved it by making sure that I was using the corresponding version of quartz composer and xcode since I have multiple versions of developer tools installed. (use both applications contained within the same developer folder).